# Cant get values from channel.members (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I can currently print a list of users from a specific voice channel whenever someone joins/leaves, but then when I try to check if a specific member is in that list it doesn't work. I never get the test print, even though that user is in the voice channel and I can see their id (174934831444583193) in the channel.members print. (I also do have the bot token at the bottom, but didn't include it for obvious reasons)

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    channel = client.get_channel(957709914111057873)

    print(channel.members)

    if "174934831444583193" in channel.members:
        print('test')


intents = discord.Intents().all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You never get the test print because you're checking if a string is in a list of `discord.Member` instances, which is always false. Id's are also ints, not strings, so even if you had just the id's it still wouldn't work.

Loop over the list of members and check if any of their id's are equal to the one you want to check, **as an int**.

```py
if any(member.id == int(your_id_here) for member in channel.members):
    ....
```